# Java mission control - save custom charts between sessions

Tags: java, jmc, java-mission-control

Java mission control is absolutely great tool for monitoring applications. There is however one thing that gets on my nerves.

I have many custom values that I chart on custom chart ("My Chart1") (request count per second, current busy threads etc.) in general tab.

Once I close Java mission control and open it again the custom chart is gone! I have to set it up again. I would also like to have an option to set the name for the chart which I could not find anywhere.

The custom values on predefined chart (Processor or memory) however preserve between sessions so I know there is some place where it stores the charts state.

How can I make jmc save my custom charts?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is supposed to work, but now when I try, I can repro the the same problem. I'll bug report this, and see if I can find some workaround.

Comment: You probably just need to remember to save (CTRL+S). And next time you open the same JVM you should see the same charts (with custom names and colors).

Answer (score 0):

Now I remember: The customizations are saved per JVM connector, and won't work if you are using the local attach connectors. But if you create a custom connection, it works fine. If your are connecting to something local, you create a connection against localhost:<port>. You can use the Control the Remote JMX Agent' utility in JMC if you don't want to restart your application, or 'jcmd ManagementAgent.start' Does this solve your problem?